# Deploying multiple MSI's into the same BizTalk Application

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, biztalk-deployment

During our development of schemas orchestrations, ports, etc.  We've been exporting MSI's and binding files for deployment into our test and ultimately production environment

So, for example, we set up a series of receive ports/locations in a single BizTalk app, for the purpose of receiving all HL7 v2 messages from our HCIS.  We then exported that to a bindings file, and imported into test.

Then, as we developed new schemas, we exported each schema into it's own msi file and deployed that into the same BizTalk application in our test environment.  We did that because the schemas are specific to the inbound messages from our HCIS.

So now, in test, we've ended up with a BizTalk application with the receive ports and schemas we need to receive messages from our HCIS.  The issue I discovered is that, if I look at the installed programs list in the control panel, I only see 1 application.  So if I want to uninstall and re-install a particular schema, I'm not sure what will happen.  For some reason, I half expected to see an entry for every msi I installed, but I suppose that because they're all going into the same BizTalk application, they are all registered in windows as the same application.  I'm betting there is a better way to do this, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can, and probably should, create different applications for each logical grouping of code. If you examine the 'deploy' section of the project properties you'll see a text box to enter your application name. When you trigger a deploy they will be placed into a separate application with the name you provide. You'll see it in the BizTalk management console.

We deploy to dev using the framework mentioned below. Then to deploy to QA right click on the application and create an MSI from that point. It will allow creating an MSI for only one application.

NOTE: the deploy setting is NOT saved globally. If another developer opens the project his project will not inherit the application name you've set.

We use the [biztalk deployment framework](http://biztalkdeployment.codeplex.com/) to help manage changes when we do development.

Answer (score 0):

> So now, in test, we've ended up with a BizTalk application with the receive ports and schemas we need to receive messages from our HCIS. The issue I discovered is that, if I look at the installed programs list in the control panel, I only see 1 application.

I can only think of two scenarios where you might observe this behaviour:

- You have multiple different MSI's (once for each schema) which you are importing into BizTalk (and hence they are appearing in the BizTalk Admin Console), but you are not running the MSI on the local machine (and so it is not appearing in 'Installed Programs'); or
- You MSI's are all named the same, in which case after the import into BizTalk and the local install, you only have a single program visible in 'Installed Programs'.

> I'm betting there is a better way to do this, any suggestions?

With regards to approach, you are certainly along the correct lines. I tend to advise clients to group logical artifacts into a single logical bucket - either project or Application - that can be deployed (and redeployed) without affecting other parts of the system.

In a HL7 scenario, one logical bucket might be Patient artifacts (schemas and supporting maps) and a second may be Financial artifacts (schemas and supporting maps). These logical buckets can either be deployed to different BizTalk Applications, or the same BizTalk Application depending on your requirements. However, the main benefit here is that they are separate and therefore *all* artifacts do not need to be redeployed if you need to make a small modification to A19 - Patient Query/Response schema for example.

How to deploy is another question entirely. I'm a massive fan of MSBuild and have written comprehensive build scripts that I tweak and reuse for each project I work on. These deployment scripts will tear down an existing environment and re-build from the ground-up, creaing Applications, deploying Resources, importing Bindings, creating Hosts and Host Instances etc. before finally starting the application. This approach removes all human error from the process and tends to be favoured by clients who often have their infrastructure teams perform the deployment rather than their development teams.

I notice that Jay mentioned the use of the BizTalk Deployment Framework. I personally struggle with this tool, partly because I need to maintain my configuration in Excel which I can't check in to source control easily.